# How to avoid this NaN result using Math.max.apply()?

Tags: javascript

How to best avoid this result, given the situation below?

```js
var p = ["!NUM", 35,2,65,7,8,9,12,121,33,99];

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

alert("Max value is: "+p.max());
```

Comment: remove the non number from the array?

Comment: Mandatory reminder to ***not*** modify built-in objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter out the non-numbers before trying to find the maximum. For example:

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this.filter(n => !isNaN(n)))
}
```

But I would recommend *not* adding new methods to built-in classes like `Array`. It's better to make your own module or class that has utility functions/methods in a namespace you control. I'd be inclined to define your `max` as a function that takes an array parameter instead of a method:

```
const max = ary => Math.max.apply(null, ary.filter(n => !isNaN(n)))
```

which you would then call as `max(p)` instead of `p.max()`.

Comment: Thank you! Weirdly enough, although ```!NUM"``` is not a number, its type does come as a number. I'm testing if the result is < 1 and it worked.

Comment: Javascript converts freely between numbers and strings; "!NUM" turns into `NaN` in my installation of Node.JS, but there are strings that don't look like numbers which numify to 0. `isNaN()` returns false on strings that look like numbers, but should return true on anything else that's not _really_ a number.